# On Application Exit for Windows Mobile (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile

First Post!

So I'm working on Windows Mobile application for a class I'm in. We have a user's data being serialized to an XML file, which is working great. But I was wondering if there's a way to tell whenever a user quits the application(by clicking the X in the top right) so I can commit the changes to the XML file at the end of the application rather than serializing after each change made. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch the form closing event and put your save code in there.

Comment: In Windows Mobile Applications do not exit, but minimize when the user presses the X button. Deactivate and and not Closing event is fired.

Comment: You can set the form to close rather than minimise by changing to MinimiseBox property of the form to false, which I assume he has done if the application is exiting.

Comment: Didn't know it was going to be so easy. I should've noticed it in the Events list! Thanks!

Comment: No worries! Keep in mind that this is fine for a class project, however for real world apps you don't only want to save on program exit.  If the user works for an hour entering data and loses power/app crashes then they'll lose all of their work.